# How to track lost phone without mobile data and location enabled?

Tags: samsung, mobile-data, geolocation, lost-phone

My relative lost his phone. The mobile data and location are both off.

I tried tracking it through Google, but it just says it's outside my house.

Is there any way to track it?

Comment: I think you know the answer already based on what you just shared here.